# How to get touch event / tap event on GMSPanoramaView

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-street-view

I have a GMSPanoramaView in my view , On clicking on GMSPanoramaView  i want to perform some action.

How can i recognize any touch/Tap event on GMSPanoramaView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GMSPanoramaView delegate:

- (void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)panoramaView didTap:(CGPoint)point;

Check out GMSPanoramaView docs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_panorama_view_delegate-p.html#member-function-documentation